# how to replace \\r\\n in pyspark dataframe

Tags: string, pyspark, replace

I have a PySpark Dataframe like this:

```
+--------------------------------------+
value                                  |
+--------------------------------------+
|"description": "this is good \\r\\n" |
```

The column name is "value" and of string type.
I want to replace

```
\\r\\n
```

in the string

```
'"description": "this is good \\r\\n"'
```

with string

```
example
```

So the string becomes

```
'"description": "this is good example"'
```

I tried

```
df = df.withColumn("newvalue", regexp_replace("value", "\\r\\n", "example"))
```

but this does not work.
Can anyone help me on this issue?

Thanks,

Arthur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DataFrame (df_1)

```
+------------------------------------+
|value                               |
+------------------------------------+
|"description": "this is good \\r\\n"|
+------------------------------------+
```

Try this

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace

df_2 = df_1.withColumn("value", regexp_replace("value", "\\\\\\\\r\\\\\\\\n", "example"))

df_2.show(truncate=False)
```

Note: We have to escape the `backslash` with a`backslash`.

***Output:***

```
+-------------------------------------+
|value                                |
+-------------------------------------+
|"description": "this is good example"|
+-------------------------------------+
```